# Ajax giving error 500

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an application that makes POST requests to a PHP file every second, via Ajax. If I try to split the string I receive in the $_POST array in php or I try to "json_decode" it, I get a 500 error.
If I do not make any of these actions, I don't get any error.
Why?

This is the PHP code that handles the Ajax request (using two POST variables):

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli(*data*);
    if (is_string($_POST["lid"]) && (is_string($_POST["price"]) || is_integer($_POST["price"])) && 0===1) {
        $li_id = $_POST["lid"];
        $esc_li_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($li_id);
        $li_price = intval($_POST["price"]);

        if ( ($li = $mysqli->query("SELECT listing_id, price, buyer_id, auction_name FROM listings WHERE listing_id = '$esc_li_id' AND schedule_requested = '1' AND finished = '0'")) && ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0) ) {
            if ( intval($li["price"]) !== $li_price ) {
                $response = array($li["price"], $li["buyer_id"], $li["auction_name"]);
            if ($logged === 1) {
                $response[] = $user_id;
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            echo "err";
        }
    } else {
        echo "err";
    }
    } else echo 'err'; ?>
```

If the code inside the outer "if" gets to be executed, it returns a 500 error. If I put a `&& 0 === 1` into the outer "if", no error is returned.

Comment: Because the code you wrote is broken, causing PHP to halt on a fatal error, causing the "500 Internal Server Error". Check the output in your network tab in the developer console, or the Apache logs on the server.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - how the heck do you get to 24k rep on here while posting answers as comments?

Comment: @jimboJonny,  Cheats.

Comment: @JimboJonny because I only post answers that actually solve problems. When I'm just identifying the question as "I didn't bring my crystal ball today, but here's a handful of pointers to solving it yourself" I don't consider it an answer (as I should).

Comment: Why not included the code here? Enjoy guessing games?

Comment: How can I check what the error is caused by?

Comment: Look in your error logs; or possibly post code here, we aren't going to guess at which PHP syntax error you have though..

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've modified the question's text.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - I get what you're saying, except the question is "why would it do this" and your comment was literally explaining why it would do that...i.e. literally an answer to the question asked. He didn't ask what line of the code is doing it (heck, when you posted that there wasn't even code in the question)...he asked why a 500 error would return when he's doing stuff with it in PHP and not when he doesn't. You told him why. That's an answer. People looking up something similar in the future will want that answer...so it shouldn't hide in the comments.

Comment: It got upvoted twice so it will sit prominently at the top of the comments, that's attention enough  ;)

Comment: May you please help me now that I posted the bugged code as well? Opening that page typing the URL in the browser doesn't give any errors, I can't understand why calling the page with Ajax does.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is trying to do something incorrectly, thus breaking the call and returning a 500 error. Check to see that the information you are receiving in the POST is what you are expecting, perhaps it is not a string and that is why your string manipulation operations aren't working

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem: even inserting a control on the variable's type (is_string) the situation does not change.

Comment: it's nearly impossible to debug this without seeing the code, just telling you why it's breaking and trying to point you in the direction of the most likely cause

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, I've pasted my code into the question's body.